# How to extend generic class to be also generic

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I am having this class : 
`public class My class <T extends Serializable>`
I want to extend it to a new generic class 
`public class Class2<T> extends My class<T>`

It gives bound mismatch error
I don't  remember the rules now actually and has no access to the material though I got the java see certificate few years ago :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type parameter `T` of your sub-class `Class2` must satisfy the type bound of the super class `Myclass`:

```
public class Class2<T extends Serializable> extends Myclass<T>
```

Otherwise `T` cannot be used as the generic type parameter of `Myclass`.